# How to remove underlining when a link is hovered over for certain links?

Tags: html, css

### HTML

```
<div class = "shared_link_post_container">
    <a id="{{post.status_id}}_shared_link_img" href="{{post.link}}" target="_blank">
        <img src="{{post.picture}}">
    </a>
    <a id="{{post.status_id}}_shared_link_text" class="shared_link_text" href="{{post.link}}" target="_blank">
        <div id="{{post.status_id}}_clickable_text_box" class="clickable_text_box">
            <br>
            <span class="shared_link_name">{{post.name}}</span>
            <br>
            <span class="unlinked shared_link_caption">{{post.caption}}</span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <span class="unlinked shared_link_description">{{post.description}}</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I want the links with the class `unlinked` to not have the underline when a link is hovered over. I tried:

### CSS

```
.unlinked {
    color: gray;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, mainly because my `unlinked` class should be `a` class. However, I don't want to remove the underlining for all my links, just the `unlinked` class.

Comment: modified jsfiddle -- its working fine - jsfiddle.net/V6ft3/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code:

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/V6ft3/5/)

```css
.unlinked {
     display: inline-block;
     color: gray;
     font-weight: normal;
     text-decoration: underline;
}

/* For hover condition */
.unlinked:hover {
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: The fiddle does not do what the question requests. It only seems to work because it has stripped away the containing a-tag.

Comment: You forgot the `a` class in your fiddle, your solution does not actually work. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/V6ft3/4/

Comment: Your answer is much better now! Thanks! Looks like the solution was to add `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 2):

Turn your `span`s into block level elements and then to this:

```
.shared_link_name {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.shared_link_name:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

[CodePen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fHDdB)

Comment: Just a question, why did I have to turn my spans to block level elements?